# Javascript: Assigning a Private Method to Private Variable

Tags: javascript, oop, private, javascript-namespaces

So I'm having some JavaScript issues.  I'm not a pro, and don't understand why this does not work.  All I am trying to do is assign my private variable to the return value of a private function.  If I set var xxx=function name() will it execute the function when I reference xxx.  Here is my code.  Note - var username=getsessionuser(); below.

```
//Namespace
var SESSIONCONTROLS=SESSIONCONTROLS || {};
SESSIONCONTROLS.APP=SESSIONCONTROLS.APP || {};


SESSIONCONTROLS.APP.User = (function () {
// defined within the local scope

//Private Variable
var username=getsessionuser();

//Privatemethod
var getsessionuser=function(){var mname='My Name'; return mname;}  

//Private Property & Method Example
var privateMethod1 = function () { alert("private method 1"); }
var privateMethod2 = function () { alert("private method 2");}

var privateProperty1 = 'foobar';
return {        
    //Public Method & Nested Namespace examples
    //Public Methods
    publicMethod1: privateMethod1,
    //nested namespace with public properties
    properties:{
        publicProperty1: privateProperty1,
        sessionname:username
    },
    //another nested namespace
    utils:{
        publicMethod2: privateMethod2
    }
  }
})();
```

This is how its called in another routine.

```
var name=SESSIONCONTROLS.APP.User.properties.sessionname;
alert(name);
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You should keep your browser developer console open to check for runtime errors.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a simple ordering problem:

```
var username=getsessionuser();

//Privatemethod
var getsessionuser=function(){var mname='My Name'; return mname;}
```

JavaScript won't complain about an undefined variable reference, because it treats all the `var` statements in a function as if they appeared at the very start of the code. However, the *initializations* in `var` statements are carried out in the sequence they appear.

Thus, at the point your code attempts to initialize `username`, the variable `getsessionuser` is not defined.

If you simply re-order those two statements so that the function is defined first, then that part at least will work.

Alternatively, you could define the function with a function declaration statement:

```
function getsessionuser() {
  var mname = "My Name";
  return mname;
}
```

Then your code will work even if you leave the initialization of `username` before the function, because function declarations are also "hoisted" up implicitly to the start of the function.

Comment: Although abusing hoisting will make most developers eyes bleed.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling getsessionuser() before it is defined. Move

```
var getsessionuser=function(){var mname='My Name'; return mname;}
```

above

```
var username=getsessionuser();
```